# Does Google read external Javascript Files that are included

Tags: javascript, seo, keyword

**Does Google read external Javascript Files that are included?**

**If I were to append non-keyword information using jquery or such would this affect keyword density?**

Now I would normally stick to plain HTML/CSS generally but I am curious about this, has anyone tested this before or know factually not *I THINK* but know or have some evidence behind them?

Comment: If they did I don't think it would be worth it to taint your js with that information.

Comment: I was more wondering if they don't that you could create a page that is only keyword rich then replace it with jquery to readable content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any external content you add dynamically to your web page (via javascript/jquery) will NOT be parsed by the search engines.

Be careful: Too much "keyword rich" will hurt you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I understand too much keyword rich. But I was more thinking about keyword density versus everything else.
Thanks ^^